# Creating a default site page title in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, default, page-title

I've got the following in my Layout file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Default page title";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
.....
```

In my View I've got:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

However, the page title is coming out as "Default page title".

How can I get the page title to display as "Home"? I only want "Default page title" to appear if I haven't specified a value for `ViewBag.Title` in the View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<title>@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Title) ? "Default page title" : ViewBag.Title)</title>
```

Comment: Cheers, I'm new to MVC and assumed it would work much like `Page.Title` does with web forms. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

Change the line:

```
ViewBag.Title = "Default page title";
```

to

```
ViewBag.Title = ViewBag.Title ?? "Default page title";
```

Comment: I like this better in that the `ViewBag` is still a central piece of information about the page title.